# Почему при возведении отрицательного числа в квадрат на python получается отрицательное число?

Tags: python, переменные, арифметика

Не могу понять почему при возведении отрицательного числа в четную степерь оно остается отрицательным на python?

```
var = -2 ** 2

print(var)
```

Результат выполнения:

> -4
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: var = (-2) ** 2  <- как у Вас написано "-" - это унарный оператор. В начале 2**2 = 4, потом -1 * 4

Comment: Ну почему выражение ***-(2 ** 2)*** отрицательное? Почему?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy это сорказм? :)))

Comment: @Виктор, нет это был сарказм. И эта фраза тоже сарказм. Как-то так. :)

Comment: с польской нотацией такого бы не случилось) `2 - 2 **`

Comment: @DaniilLoban [2 2 ** -] - вроде так обратная польская запись

Comment: так будет -4 а я про 4 писал `(-2) ** 2`

Comment: Ясно :))))))))))

Answer (score 2):

Потому что это выражение равносильно `-(2 ** 2)`. Подробнее в [таблице приоритетов операторов](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Возведение в степень на одну строку выше перемены знака:

```
expr = '-2 ** 2'
print(ast.dump(ast.parse(expr, mode='eval'), indent=4))
```

> ```
> Expression(
>     body=UnaryOp(
>         op=USub(),
>         operand=BinOp(
>             left=Constant(value=2),
>             op=Pow(),
>             right=Constant(value=2))))
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего. Надо '-2' взять в скобки. Так же работает и в базовой математике.

```
var = (-2)**2

print(var)
```